# package mathspec error

Tags: fontspec, mathspec

I am trying to use the mathspec package and I cannot get it to load due to a fontspec error from something in the configuration file.
I don't know how it can be more simple

The MWE is below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts[Scale=MatchLowercase]{NewCenturySchlbk}
\setallsansfonts[Scale=1]{Arial} % primarily used for captions
\setallmonofonts{Courier New}

\begin{document}

The quadratic formula is:
\begin{equation}
x = \frac{-\beta\pm\sqrt{4\times A\times \delta}}{2A}
\end{equation}

when $\sqrt{4\times A\times \Delta} >0$ there are two real roots. 
\end{document}
```

Here is the logfile

This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit) entering extended mode
(C:/TEMP/MathFont/MathFont.tex LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2020-02-08>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\report.cls" Document Class: report 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/xelatex/mathspec\mathspec.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifxetex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg")))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.642 \define@choicekey
[eu]
?

Comment: Sorry, I get no error (after changing the font, that I don't have, with TeX Gyre Schola). It seems you're missing the loading of `xkeyval.sty`; on my console, the line just after `fontspec.cfg` corresponds to loading `xkeyval.sty`.

Comment: Try using `Cambria` as your maths font, not `New Century Schoolbook`.